# Applescript: Notification centre alert with specific Icon

Tags: notifications, applescript

I understand that there is a very limited number of options to do with the Applescript notification alert call, but I am curious as to whether alerts can be called with icons or specified images to better identify them?

I ask this as i have seen it employed by other Applications which use the Notification Centre, and each Application has its notifications heralded by its own Application Icons.

Example:

[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it's not possible to change the icon programatically.

A workaround is to save the script as application and change the icon (applet.icns) in the Resources folder of the package.